# entity framework doesnt allow to save data in db

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model, entity

i am using entityframework codefirst in my application. 
i have 2 tables: 
1.Order
2.Orderdetails
i want to collect data from a form and save it in these 2 tables in one action.
my form uses a viewmodel called "OrderViewModel".
i want to save data in "Order" table and "Orderdetail" table when user clicks submit. but i have blow error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>
> 'Amooshahryar.Models.Order', but this dictionary requires a model item
>   of type 'Amooshahryar.Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel'.

my form uses 'Amooshahryar.Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel' and in actionresult i want to save data in Order table witch uses 'Amooshahryar.Models.Order'.

i cant understand what cuases problem.
here is my code:

```
 public ActionResult آدرس_و_پرداخت(FormCollection values)
    {


        var order = new Order() {};

        TryUpdateModel(order);

        int totalcartprice = 0;

        try
        {
            order.Username = User.Identity.Name;
            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.DeliveryStatusID = 1;

            TryUpdateModel(order);

                //Save Order
                db.Orders.Add(order);
                db.SaveChanges(); <===========here i get error

                //Process the order


            //And rest of the code that i havent write here
        }
        catch
        {
            //Invalid - redisplay with errors
            return View(order);
        }
    }
```

any help is appritiated ...

thank you.

Edit:

This is my stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Amooshahryar.Models.Order', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Amooshahryar.Models.ViewModels.OrderViewModel'.]
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +378
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary.set_Model(Object value) +47
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +614
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1..ctor(ViewDataDictionary viewDataDictionary) +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +98
>      System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.set_ViewData(ViewDataDictionary value) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +425
>      System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
>      System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +321
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9748493
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +159

Comment: What's the exception you get? Have you defined a primary key in the Orders table ?

Comment: Why are you using a FormCollection object as the input to your action method? Use a strongly typed object matching your actual fields. Probably it should be your viewmodel object.

Comment: Your error (I assume it's the line `return View(order);` causing it? You didn't actually mention) is simply because `order` is not an OrderViewModel object, it's an Order object. Your view expects an OrderViewModel, you can't send it something else. You need to create the correct type of object to send to the view. Take a basic MVC tutorial, it will show you all of this kind of thing.

Comment: @AlkisGiamalis i have wrote the error massage and yes i have defind PK

Comment: @ADyson what is problem with FormCollection? is it bad practice?

Comment: @ADyson no i have test it line by line and i understood it had error at line  db.SaveChanges();

Comment: The error is an mvc-error. Sure, that the ´db.SaveChanges()´ is the correct row?

Comment: It's not the best practice, no. FormCollection is just a loose collection of items, if the request is coming from a view which has a strongly-type model, like your OrderViewModel object, then it's simpler to use that type as the input type, because the form you submitted will already have the field names correct for that object, ASP.NET will map the fields from the request into your object and then you can simply use that C# object directly in your code, with all the correct properties. Again consult any introductory MVC tutorial and you'll see they always use the viewmodel object.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that db.SaveChanges could produce that error. That line a) does not deal with receiving an object and b) the database expects an Order object, which you gave it. It does not expect an OrderViewModel object, and you didn't give it one, so it cannot produce the error stated. That error is generated by the MVC view engine when trying to render the view. Nothing to do with saving to the database

Comment: @kara I didnt understand your question.

Comment: Looking at your code though, there is a code smell...your return statement is inside a "catch" block. So I think what is happening is...1) Your db.SaveChanges fails for some reason, and an exception is thrown. 2) The code moves to the Catch block because of this. 3) You ignore the exception, don't log it or anything (so you don't know what the exception was, which is not good) and try to execute a `return` statement. Unfortunately your `return` statement also fails because you passed the wrong type of object. This then produces the exception you see on your screen, because that's not caught

Comment: @ADyson i added stack trace. can u understand the problem from stack trace?

Comment: Yes, see my above comment. You are catching and then ignoring a database exception and then seeing an exception which is the result of the bad code inside your catch block. So you have two problems, one of which you are catching and throwing away without examining the problem.

Comment: Check which line throws the exception. As ADyson wrote: ´db.SaveChanges()´ cannot do this. The exception you get tells you, that your Data-Class has got a problem. I bet your second return - which you did't show us - is your problem.

Comment: @kara read my comments, since OP reported that db.SaveChanges failed, we should assume it goes into the catch block. The code in the catch block is incorrect and will throw another exception, uncaught, and this is the one OP is seeing.

Comment: @ADyson: good point. Did't think so far.

Comment: Don't squash exceptions like this. If an exception happens it's because something unusual happened and something is actually wrong, and so it's fine for the application to crash. Don't hide it, and please always log it and investigate it. Try-catch is for catching only unavoidable exceptions. A database crash should not be unavoidable, it should be unusual. Also if your `return` statement within the catch did succeed, the user gets no feedback that there's a problem and is left wondering why they're on the same screen again. Meanwhile you as the developer get no notice that your app is broken.

Comment: @ADyson you were right. i couldnt understand the problem becuase i was getting another Error From my catch block. thank you.

Comment: @ADyson my problem was from a foriegn key in another table and now it works fine. write your comment about try catch as an answer.

Comment: @AshkanHafezi I added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is happening:

1) Your db.SaveChanges fails for some reason, and an exception is thrown.

2) The code moves to the Catch block because of this.

3) You ignore the exception, and try to execute a return statement. Unfortunately your return statement also fails because you passed the wrong type of object. This then produces the exception you see on your screen, because that's not caught.

Don't squash exceptions like this. If an exception happens it's because something unusual happened and something is actually wrong, and so it's fine for the application to crash. Don't hide it, and please always log it and investigate it. Try-catch is for catching only unavoidable exceptions. A database crash should not be unavoidable, it should be unusual. Also if your return statement within the catch did succeed, the user gets no feedback that there's a problem and is left wondering why they're on the same screen again. Meanwhile you as the developer get no notice that your app is broken